# Forcing mathematica not to substitute some terms in an expression

Tags: simplifying-expressions, replacement, assignment

I have an expression `c` which should be defined before the function and a function f defined as follows:

```
c=Sqrt[a^2-b^2];
F[x,y,z]= c*x+c^2*y+c^3*z
```

Evaluation of this expression will give:

```
Sqrt[a^2 - b^2]*x + (a^2 - b^2)*y + (a^2 - b^2)^(3/2)*z
```

How can I make Mathematica temporarily not to substitute c when evaluating F?

i.e. I want `c` to be substituted only by applying `FullSimplify`

Comment: Are you looking for something like `Block` or `Module` to protect `c`?

Comment: Can you please explain more? Both 'c' and 'f' are global. @thorimur

Comment: But `c` is simpler than `Sqrt[a^2-b^2]`, so I doubt it would be substituted by `FullSimplify` unless you use a custom `ComplexityFunction` to force it. Even then, simplifying is an uncertain way to try to effect a substitution.

Comment: Maybe the most simple thing is to define the function `F` with another variable, say, `c1` as follows: `F[c1_,x_,y_,z_]:=c1*x + c1^2*y + c1^3*z`. As soon as you will need to substitute the expression for `c`, you simply evaluate `F[c, x, y, z]`. Done.

Answer (score 3):

You could always make a Rule and choose to apply it or not.

```
cRule = {c -> Sqrt[a^2 - b^2]};
F[x_, y_, z_] = c*x + c^2*y + c^3*z
(*   c^3 z + c^2 y + c x   *)
```

or

```
F[x, y, z] /. cRule
(*   x Sqrt[a^2 - b^2] + y (a^2 - b^2) + z (a^2 - b^2)^(3/2)   *)
```